# GLUT native window handle

Tags: glut, freeglut

Once I created a window with GLUT, can I get the native handle of that window some how on Linux?

I know this will break portability.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use native APIs for accessing the current window. I have no example of doing that but you can see this link for an idea:

> https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/161329-Get-Window-Handle-Dev-Contx-Ren-Contx-in-GLUT

You may want to instead try GLFW or SDL for your windows management; both provide more robust input handling than GLUT does.

Comment: Thank you, but Your link is Windows, while my question is about Linux version of GLUT.